# hibernate - cache collections accessed by repository without having a set

Tags: hibernate, caching, domain-driven-design

Usually in hibernate we have lots of parent/child relationships with `HashSet`s. So the parent has a Set of children. This can be easily cached in second level cache with hibernate collection cache. When you add or remove objects to the set the cache is invalidated.

Now we want to drop the set relationship on the parent object. This is because following DDD (Domain driven Design) semantics the child is not part of the aggregate root of the parent. The child is an aggregate root on its own. But the child class still has a relationship to the parent.

So we started using a repository to access the children with methods like this:

```
public Set<Child> getChildren(Parent parent) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Child.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.naturalId().set("parent", parent));
    criteria.setCacheable(true); // does not work here!
    return criteria.list();
}
```

The problem is the `setCacheable`. As our child has two naturalId which is the parent and its own naturalId (for example a name).

The hibernate query cache with naturalIds does not work if I use only one of the two naturalIds as hibernate does not recognise adding or deleting more entities with repository methods like save() or delete().

when we use it without `Restrictions-naturalId()` we can use the normal query cache but this one gets invalidated if any child is added or modified. This is common problem with the query cache and not specific to our problem.

Therefore we tried to write our own CollectionRepository ending up with a class like this:

```
public abstract class CollectionRepositoryHibernate<T extends PersistableEntity, E extends PersistableEntity> extends StandardRepositoryHibernate<T> implements
        CollectionRepository<T, E>
{
    private Class<T>    entityClass = getGenericClass();
    private Class<E>    parentClass = getGenericParentClass();

    @Override
    public void save ( T persistableEntity )
    {
        evictCache(persistableEntity);
        super.save(persistableEntity);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> getCollection ( E persistableEntity )
    {
        return getNaturalCollectionCriteria(persistableEntity).list();
    }

    protected Criteria getNaturalCollectionCriteria ( E persistableEntity )
    {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.naturalId().set(getPropertyName(), persistableEntity));
        criteria.setCacheable(true);
        criteria.setCacheRegion(getCacheRegion(persistableEntity.getId()));
        return criteria;
    }

    private String getPropertyName ( )
    {
        ClassMetadata classMetadata = getSession().getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(entityClass);
        int[] naturalIdentifierProperties = classMetadata.getNaturalIdentifierProperties();
        String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
        for (int i : naturalIdentifierProperties)
        {
            String propertyName = propertyNames[i];
            try
            {
                Field field = entityClass.getDeclaredField(propertyName);
                Class<?> type = field.getType();
                if (type.equals(parentClass))
                {
                    return propertyName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No property name found");
    }

    private void evictCache ( T persistableEntity )
    {
        Cache cache = getSession().getSessionFactory().getCache();
        String cacheRegion = getCacheRegion(getCollectionId(persistableEntity));
        cache.evictQueryRegion(cacheRegion);
    }

    protected String getCacheRegion ( Integer id )
    {
        return entityClass + "#" + id;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete ( T persistableEntity )
    {
        evictCache(persistableEntity);
        super.delete(persistableEntity);
    }

    protected Integer getCollectionId ( T persistableEntity )
    {
        try
        {
            Field field = persistableEntity.getClass().getDeclaredField(getPropertyName());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            PersistableEntity parentEntity = (PersistableEntity) field.get(persistableEntity);
            return parentEntity.getId();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no collection id found, e");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Class<E> getGenericParentClass ( )
    {
        Class<E> result = null;
        Type type = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
        {
            ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
            Type[] fieldArgTypes = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
            result = (Class<E>) fieldArgTypes[1];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**The trick we use here is to have one cache region per collection.**

When it comes to save or delete we evict this cache region. It works fine, but has some drawbacks:

- we need lots of cache regions. So far we don't know if there are some limitations or performance considerations to make.
- As the names of the cache regions are not known before you can't configure the cache regions, like setting the maximum number of elements or the time-to-live

Summary: we don't want a set in our parent. We need to have second level collection cache which is not always invalidated if an entity is added or removed (like it is the case with usual query cache).

Do you know a proper way to have a collection cache which are not mapped with a parent/child relationship in a set?

Comment: If parent is Order and child is OrderLine, your interpretation of DDD is simply wrong. The aggregate root will reference its child entities by collections, not repositories. If the child is an aggregate root by itself, I would say that your approach is correct (no explicit child collection reference).

Comment: The child is an aggregate root by itself. I have updated my question.